# Почему треть картинки уходит за пределы экрана?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Почему у меня треть картинки уходит за пределы экрана?
Верстаю через bootstrap

```css
header.header {
  background-image: url(../images/top_bg.png);
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header class="header navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="navbar collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsive-menu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
          <li>
            <a href="#">SERVICES</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">OUR TEAM</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">CONTACT US</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте background-size: cover; - Масштабирует изображение с сохранением пропорций так, чтобы его ширина или высота равнялась ширине или высоте блока.

Comment: может так ? background-position: center top; + background-size: cover;

Comment: Да спасибо, помогло. Не знал про это честно говоря )

Comment: @soledar10 Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы задать положение фонового изображения используют [background-position](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-position), а для масштабирования [background-size](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-size) - cover

Пример (использую сокращенную запись для background)

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header{
  min-height: 400px;
  background: url('http://sfondiweb.altervista.org/natura/natura2.jpg') no-repeat center top;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
```

[Свойство background](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background)

[w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/background](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties#Background)